# Protobuf cannot find shared libraries

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have installed protobuf by using following commands:

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

However when I run `protoc` I get following error:

```
protoc: error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 264, accepted):

```
sudo ldconfig
```

or

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: @Bagzerg `protoc` needs to know where to look for shared libraries. (It cannot search your whole system). This is similar to how `PATH` helps in locating executables. See this [post here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45106/19506) that explains `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: as of Feb 2016, installed protocol-buffers 2.6.1 on debian 8, and this solved the problem for missing libraries. Thanks @KshitizSharma

Comment: i used the second method "export..." , but i dont know why the first method doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. It did the job. However, I think, it is more appropriate to use this: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`

Comment: Lol for me restarting the machine fixed the problem

Comment: @ponir This depends on whether there are multiple temporary paths after the user logs in.Mostly, `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` is much cleaner.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use

```
$ sudo ldconfig # refresh shared library cache.
```

[as stated at the installation page](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md)

Answer (score 6):

This issue can be resolved by following these steps:

1. vim /etc/ld.so.conf
2. /usr/local/lib(add it in .conf)

Comment: Missing "ldconfig" which is probably the step that is most required.

Answer (score 3):

This issue can be resolved by following these steps:

```
sudo make uninstall
sudo make distclean
sudo make clean
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

This cleans the current installation and installs protobuf at /usr
Run ldconfig to update ld.so.cache after making sure that /usr/local/lib is listed in /etc/ld.so.conf. i.e.
Edit /etc/ld.so.conf and append /usr/local/lib to it and run ldconfig

Comment: You've got two separate solutions mixed together here (using ldconfig and simply installing to /usr).  Very confusing answer.